# Map database type to concrete Java class

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc, metadata

### Background

Map a column data type to its corresponding Java class.

### Problem

A query returns meta information from a database:

```
SELECT
  rb.object_schema,
  rb.object_name,
  rb.column_name
FROM
  dictionary.resource_bundle rb
```

For example, this query returns (the self-referential):

```
dictionary, resource_bundle, column_name
```

Where 'dictionary' is the schema name, 'resource_bundle' is the object_name, and 'column_name' is the column_name.

It would be great to do something like:

```
SELECT
  rb.object_schema,
  rb.object_name,
  rb.column_name,
  rb.column_type
FROM
  dictionary.resource_bundle rb
```

And have this query return:

```
dictionary, resource_bundle, column_name, varchar
```

Then use JDBC to discover that `varchar` is [mapped](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-jdbc/2010-10/msg00062.php) to `java.lang.String`.

### Questions

1. In PostgreSQL, how do you determine what type is used to store the data, given a schema name, object name (guaranteed to be table or view), and column name?
2. In a database-neutral fashion (leveraging JDBC), how do you determine the mapping a database uses for a given data type?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Solution

The answer is more complicated than using the `getMetaData` method because there is no direct mapping from the integer types returned by the `getMetaData` method and the full class name. This solution requires two pieces of code:

- Implementing a method to obtain the `java.sql.Types` constant integer value.
- Creating a method to translate that value to a class name.

### Java Type Method

The following method retrieves the meta information:

```
  public String getJavaType( String schema, String object, String column )
    throws Exception {
    String fullName = schema + '.' + object + '.' + column;
    DatabaseMetaData metaData = getConnection().getMetaData();
    ResultSet columnMeta = metaData.getColumns( null, schema, object, column );
    String javaType = null;

    if( columnMeta.first() ) {
      int dataType = columnMeta.getInt( "DATA_TYPE" );
      javaType = SQLTypeMap.convert( dataType );
    }
    else {
      throw new Exception( "Unknown database column " + fullName + '.' );
    }

    return javaType;
  }
```

### Static Conversion Method

The constant integer values must be translated to a class name. This can be accomplished as follows:

```
import java.sql.Types;

/**
 * Converts database types to Java class types.
 */
public class SQLTypeMap {
    /**
     * Translates a data type from an integer (java.sql.Types value) to a string
     * that represents the corresponding class.
     * 
     * @param type
     *            The java.sql.Types value to convert to its corresponding class.
     * @return The class that corresponds to the given java.sql.Types
     *         value, or Object.class if the type has no known mapping.
     */
    public static Class<?> toClass(int type) {
        Class<?> result = Object.class;

        switch (type) {
            case Types.CHAR:
            case Types.VARCHAR:
            case Types.LONGVARCHAR:
                result = String.class;
                break;

            case Types.NUMERIC:
            case Types.DECIMAL:
                result = java.math.BigDecimal.class;
                break;

            case Types.BIT:
                result = Boolean.class;
                break;

            case Types.TINYINT:
                result = Byte.class;
                break;

            case Types.SMALLINT:
                result = Short.class;
                break;

            case Types.INTEGER:
                result = Integer.class;
                break;

            case Types.BIGINT:
                result = Long.class;
                break;

            case Types.REAL:
            case Types.FLOAT:
                result = Float.class;
                break;

            case Types.DOUBLE:
                result = Double.class;
                break;

            case Types.BINARY:
            case Types.VARBINARY:
            case Types.LONGVARBINARY:
                result = Byte[].class;
                break;

            case Types.DATE:
                result = java.sql.Date.class;
                break;

            case Types.TIME:
                result = java.sql.Time.class;
                break;

            case Types.TIMESTAMP:
                result = java.sql.Timestamp.class;
                break;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Note that different databases can have different variations on the mapping.

Answer (score 2):

JDBC provides the means to introspect database meta information.

From a JDBC Connection, call [getMetaData](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Connection.html#getMetaData()) and [getColumns](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) drill down from there to get information for schemas, tables and, columns.