# How to get java Class object according JDBCType

Tags: java, jdbc, metadata

I'm trying to implement data transfer from one DB type to another via JDBC.

With `connection.getMetaData().getColumnType()` I can get JDBCType of column.

How can I use it to get java Class object to be able to use `resultSet.getObject(i, XXX.class)`?

Of course I can do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/5253901/7849631

Does any library already implements this accoridng DB vendor? Or maybe there is special result set floating somewhere?

Here's a simple example to understand my problem:

```
private List<Map<String, Object>> readDataFromResultSet(ResultSet resultSet, Map<String, JDBCType> columnNamesTypes) throws SQLException {
        List<Map<String, Object>> dataToTransfer = new ArrayList<>();
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            Map<String, Object> value = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            for (String columnName : columnNamesTypes.keySet()) {
                final JDBCType type = columnNamesTypes.get(columnName);
                value.put(columnName, resultSet.getObject(columnName, **convertJDBCTypeToClass**(type)));
            }
            dataToTransfer.add(value);
        }
        return dataToTransfer;
    }
```

UPDATE: this has been resolved with org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.JdbcTypeJavaClassMappings

Comment: Why not just use `getObject(int)`? It should already return an object of the type correct for the returned type value.

Comment: What's wrong with `rs.getObject()`? In the end, that gives you the object of the appropriate type based on colum data type. Or do you need to convert to non-default types?

Comment: `ResultSet` exposes all sort of getters for various types. They don't work for you?

Comment: I have to read object of concrete type from DB from ResultSet. I get this type from getColumnType(). So with getObject(columnName, Integer.Class) I can get Integer. I don't want to use mapping like if JDBCType.equals(INTEGER) then use getInt instead of getObject. I hope there's any library that implemented this already

Comment: Again, what is the problem with using `getObject(int)`? If the sql type reported by the metadata is `Types.INTEGER` or `JDBCType.INTEGER`, then a JDBC compliant implementation will return an `Integer` when using `getObject(int)`, etc. You seem to be looking for the solution to a problem **that does not exist** (or: should not exist with a JDBC compliant driver). And if you do have such a problem then post a [mcve].